# Create Non-Culture Based ResourceManager for ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, database, customization, resourcemanager

I am working on an ASP.Net application that is company specific in that when users login, they login using their username, password and company id.  I am trying to find the best way to allow each company to customize certain labels within the software.  For instance, there is a field that we globally call "Unique Identifier".  On a per company basis, they may want to rename the field to be "Employee Badge Number", "HR Id Code" or whatever every they want.  I was looking at possibly extending the ResourceProvider to using a DB instead of the RESX files, however, it seems like the ResourceProvider is heavily based on culture/languages changes rather than customization.

Has anyone developed similar functionality in an application?  Did you extend the ResourceProvider or go the completely custom route?

I have been searching for possible solutions all week and am coming up dry.  My fall back is to just create something completely custom, but I worry about losing out of the building efficiency of the ResourceProvider.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use the resx files by providing a GUID. The customers will have the ability to edit the labels in what ever they want. You have just to deal with the xml of the resx files.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a customization / personalization issue than a localisation issue. I would not use the ResourceProvider for this.